# $http.get() always fails von Windows Phone (7 & 8)

Tags: angularjs, windows-phone-7, cordova, windows-phone-8

My app (angularjs + cordova/phonegap) loads content (json) from a remote server, which is working nicely on android and ios, but on windows phone the requests always fails. My code looks like this:

```
$http.get( url )
  .success(function( response ){
     ...
  })
  .error(function( data , status , headers , config ){
     console.log( data , status , headers , config );
  });
```

Unfortunately I don't get any real error message (data, status and headers are simply 'undefined').

Comment: Don't know if this would help you: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/6574

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I tried those solutions already and neither of them worked. My request url is correct, there is no "x-wmapp0"-part in it, but the real url.

Comment: Which version of Cordova are you using ? Does this issue happens in debug or only on release ? Is the SSL certificate of the remote server valid/ self-signed ?

Comment: I am using Cordova 2.9.1, but it's also not working on real WP7/8 devices if I build the app via build.phonegap.com with the current version. It happens on debug and release, I don't use a SSL certificate.

Comment: Update: I also tried to use jQuery 1.9 and 2.0 for the ajax request and build it in pure javascript, but everything fails.

Comment: Your web service is created using which platform ? ASP.net or PHP ?

Comment: Facing the same problem here with my UWP... But in my case it worked only once on Windows 10 (pc), but after that it is saying **The download of the specified resource has failed.** Not working at all on WP 8.1 ... Yet to test on real android device... Any luck finding any solution? @dominikweber

Answer (score 1):

You can try this...

```
$http.get('http://myserver.com/phones.json').then(function(data) {
  $scope.phones = data;
}, function(err) { alert('Oh no! An error!'});
```

I think you want to use `then()`, which takes two functions as arguments — the first for success, and the second for error. `$http.get()` returns a promise which is acted upon by `then()`.

Check out the angular debug tool [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en). It shows you what is available in scopes, and shows performance data.